# PyCharm printing before imports?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am a complete Python beginner (CS student who only knows Java at this point) and I'm currently using PyCharm to try to learn. However, I've been encountering this problem which I don't even know how to search for because I don't understand what's happening. When I try to run:

```
print('test')
```

in the PyCharm console, I get this output:

[image: Test code]

The print statement happens before the imports and seemingly before Python even initializes. I've been encountering some strange interactions as a result of this. For example, if I change the print to an input(), the program will take input but the string in the argument of the input function will not be printed. Can anyone explain what's going on here? Should I be running my programs differently? There is my run configuration:

[image: Run configuration]

Comment: PyCharm runs some code for you when you open a new interactive console. How do you run your code?

Comment: @Norrius I’ve just been using the regular run (green triangle, Ctrl-Shift-F10).

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include a screenshot of your Run Configuration? You should be able to find it under the configurations drop-down, then “Edit Configurations”.

Comment: @Norrius I've edited it to include what I think is the Run Configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyCharm seems to run your script in PyDev console, which is what it uses for the Python Console tab where your interactive console lives. This results in some Python code being automatically executed to set up the environment (look for “starting script” in settings).

Try unchecking the “Run with Python console” checkbox. It is the one after “Emulate terminal”, in my PyCharm version it is called “Show command line afterwards”.